# Code stops functioning after button is clicked (in Firefox, IE, Safari, but NOT in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have made a lightbox-style gallery using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ncD9H/.
What works in this fiddle and Chrome does not work on any other browser.

I have thumbnails inside `<a>` tags:

```
<div id="gallery">
            <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/01.jpg">
                <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/01.jpg">
            </a>
            <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/02.jpg">
                <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/02.jpg">
            </a>
            <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/03.jpg">
                <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/03.jpg">
            </a>
</div>
```

And when I click the thumbnail, it switches to the fullview with the following jQuery script:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('.lightbox').fadeIn(200);
    $('#main').foggy();
    var imageSource =$(this).attr('href');
    $('.lightbox>img').attr('src',imageSource);
    });
```

The fullview is switched off when the full image is clicked on:

```
$('.lightbox>img').click(function(){
        $('.lightbox').fadeOut(200);
        $('#main').foggy(false);
    });
```

When I click a thumbnail and open the fullview, and then click the full image to exit lightbox, `$('.trigger').click(function(e){ ...});` does not work at all. When I click a thumbnail a second time, the browser just navigates to the full image.

So I've tried the following:
I've refreshed the page, clicked a thumbnail to open the fullview, then exited the full view by clicking the picture again. Then, in the console, I've typed:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I clicked the thumbnail again, the browser did nothing, as dictated by the function. But I am guessing that this means the original function, for some reason, becomes inaccessible for a second clicking. Why does this happen, why does it work on chrome, and how can I fix it?

Note: `foggy()` is a jQuery plugin that blurs the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as expected (not opening the link right?) in Safari (`6.0.5`) and Firefox (`23.0.1`) for me. It's a silly question but did you try to clear the cache ?

Anyhow, if you don't want at anytime that the browser send the user to the linked picture, I would suggest you to not use `<a>`. It will save you a lot of time of figuring out how to prevent all browsers to do what `<a>` is meant to do.

Comment: In fiddle it works. In the original .html file, it does not. I've just tried clearing the cache, but it didn't resolve the issue. I've also replaced `<a>`s with `<div>`s, but it caused the whole code to malfunction. `$('.lightbox').hide();` doesn't work now. I can't see how the two would be related in any way.

Comment: Well, there must be something different from the fiddle and your html file. Did you check for any others JS scripts that could mess with this one ? or not the same jquery version ? or the class `.trigger`is removed somewhere ? Also you could try by changing `$('.trigger').click(func)` by `$(document).on('click', '.trigger', func);`

Comment: Well, if it broke something else, I guess you have other JS scripts doing job on those anchors too, so that might be them which mess around you.

Comment: I've fixed the lighbox issue. I have the script in the body tag, along with the jquery source link.  I made the `<a>`s into `<div>` tags, and `href="filename"` into `data-file="filename"`.  I've also corrected the selectors accordingly.  I'm back to square one. This time, nothing happens when I click the thumbnails (the function does not work at all, again). I've uploaded the full .html file here: [link](http://www.tandemtr.com/test/test3.html)

Comment: changing `$('.trigger').click(func)` by `$(document).on('click', '.trigger', func);` seems to work. I'm not sure why $.click only works once, maybe it's because of some closure effect.